# Behavior of $y$ as $t\to \infty$ of $y' = 2t - 1 - y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Behavior of $y$ as $t\to\infty$ of $y' = 2t - 1 - y^2$

This is a problem from the Brannan and Boyce textbook Differential Equations. The question asks to determine the behavior of $y$ as $t \to\infty$ by drawing a direction field, and then lists the answer as "$y \to -\infty$ or is asymptotic to $\sqrt{2t - 1}$ depending on the initial value of $y$". It's ridiculous to find this behavior by drawing out a direction field. Is there a mathematical way to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction field is definitely the way to go in this problem, but if you insist:

If you substitute $y(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} \log u(t) = \dfrac{u'(t)}{u(t)}$
the differential equation becomes
$$ u''  + (1-2 t) u = 0$$

This leads to the solutions involving Airy functions, because Airy's differential equation $y'' = t y$ is obtained by a change of independent variable.
$$ u = c_1 \; \text{Ai}(2^{-2/3}(2t-1)) + c_2 \; \text{Bi}(2^{-2/3}(2t-1))$$
where Ai and Bi are Airy functions.
If $c_2 \ne 0$, the Bi term is dominant for large $t$, and 
$$y(t) = \dfrac{u'(t)}{u(t)} = \sqrt{2t-1} + O(1/t)\ \text{ as } t \to +\infty$$
If $c_2 = 0$, there is only the Ai term, and then 
$$ y(t) = \dfrac{u'(t)}{u(t)} = - \sqrt{2t-1} + O(1/t) \ \text{ as } t \to +\infty$$
However, we should also watch out for solutions that have the denominator $u(t)$ hitting $0$ at finite $t$.  In this case $y \to -\infty$, not as $t \to \infty$ but rather as you approach a finite value of $t$ (the direction field shows that it is $y \to -\infty$, not $y \to +\infty$).  The explicit solution then comes back from $+\infty$, but this is not really the same solution.